# Seeding Roles with RoleManager in Asp.Net Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have been seeding my database by using this link

[Seeding Db with AspNet Core](https://garywoodfine.com/how-to-seed-your-ef-core-database/)

Now when seeding I also would like to access `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` and `RoleManager<IdentityRole>`.

However, as this is called in the configure method I cannot find the service using;

`var RoleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();`

`var UserManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();`

How would I access this inject this in so I can seed my roles etc?

Comment: Make your seed method part of a service rather than an extension method, then just inject the UserManager/RoleManager as you would normally. Try to avoid using `GetRequiredService`.

Comment: sorry could you expand a bit on this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to give you a tip, I use this in our Startup.cs. I hope this might help you.

```
// Inside the public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)

var scopeFactory = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();

var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope();

var roleManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();

new UserRoleSeed(roleManager).Seed(); // Where UserRoleSeeding happens
```

You also need to inherit this `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` in your DbContext. Like the sample code below:

```
public class ProjectDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
```

In implementing this in your controller, I would suggest that you use Dependency Injection similar to the code below:

```
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;
private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager;

public TestingController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager){
   this.userManager = userManager;
   this.roleManager = roleManager;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Index(){
   // Test in getting userManager
   var user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, out of interest then do you split all your seeding out to seperate classes? i.e. UserSeed etc etc?

Comment: Is it for your concern in using `UserManager<ApplicationUser> and RoleManager<IdentityRole>` so you can use it in your controller? :)

Comment: Yes I suppose those are the main one that and my main DataContext, I am just trying to make sure everything is setup correctly, as I like the seperating my concerns :)

Comment: When regards to your DbContext, you should inherit the `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`. I included it in my answer. :)